# I've updated my home city, but my old one shows all over the place. How can I fix this?

Tags: support, network-profile

I've changed my home city from Oxford to Vancouver, but Oxford still shows up in lots of places, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/story/tomashoxford. How can I fix this?

Here's where I changed it:

On Stack Overflow:

[image]

On stackexchange.com:

[image]

---

Here's another example of my old home city showing, on job preferences at Stack Overflow:

[image]

Comment: Did you already try to blame [caching](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/221414#221414)?

Comment: This is off topic here. Stack Overflow has its own meta.

Comment: Off topic? They asked about how to do something on *all sites*, on a site which provides support for questions relating to *all sites*. :stroking-chin:

Comment: @James All the examples pointed out here have to do with Stack Overflow's job engine. I just tested this, and it works fine on other sites. As such, it's off-topic here.

Comment: Ah fair enough :)

Comment: yep, that fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to also change your location, in your [developer story settings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/join), otherwise it will show the wrong one in some places.